# Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class 'Symfony\Component\Console\Cursor' not found

Tags: laravel, laravel-jetstream

Buen ías espero puedan ayudarme estoy instalando un proyecto de Laravel con Jetstream y al ejecutar el comando:

`laravel new test-app --jet`

Muestra lo siguiente:

> Which Jetstream stack do you prefer?   [0] livewire   [1] inertia
>
> > Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class 'Symfony\Component\Console\Cursor' not found in C:\Users\JosÃ©
> > Rivas\AppData\Roaming\Composer\vendor\symfony\console\Helper\QuestionHelper.php:245
> > Stack trace:
> > #0 C:\Users\JosÃ© Rivas\AppData\Roaming\Composer\vendor\symfony\console\Helper\QuestionHelper.php(141):
> > Symfony\Component\Console\Helper\QuestionHelper->autocomplete(Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Style\SymfonyStyle),
> > Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Question\ChoiceQuestion), Resource id
> > #1, Object(Closure))
> > #1 C:\Users\JosÃ© Rivas\AppData\Roaming\Composer\vendor\symfony\console\Helper\QuestionHelper.php(68):
> > Symfony\Component\Console\Helper\QuestionHelper->doAsk(Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Style\SymfonyStyle),
> > Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Question\ChoiceQuestion))
> > #2 C:\Users\JosÃ© Rivas\AppData\Roaming\Composer\vendor\symfony\console\Helper\QuestionHelper.php(469):
> > Symfony\Component\Console\Helper\QuestionHelper->Symfony\Component\Console\Helper{closure}()
> > #3 C:\Users\JosÃ© Rivas\AppData\Roaming\Composer\vendor\symfo in C:\Users\JosÃ©
> > Rivas\AppData\Roaming\Composer\vendor\symfony\console\Helper\QuestionHelper.php
> > on line 245

Esto lo estoy haciendo por el CMD de windows, tambien he usado la terminal de visual studio code pero da el mismo error.

No he conseguido ninguna respuesta sobre este error en especifico instale de nuevo el Composer, pero no da resultado tampoco, estoy comenzando a probar laravel.jetstream pero no me ha dado buenos resultados he visto varios tutoriales y a todos parace funcionalres perfectamente, pero yo no he tenido exito.

Estoy explorando esta herramienta del laravel 8 para ejecutar un proyecto a un cliente y no he podido avanzar, si alguien tiene alguna respuesta o,sulicion se lo agradeceria*

Comment: Solo por aclarar que versión de composer usas?

Comment: Version 2.0.8 @BetaM